# Aggregating Values From 2 DF in R

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial

I am trying to calculate the cumulative confirmed cases rate (i.e. cases per 10000 population) and the cumulative death rate by month from two DF and plot it into a map.

Here's the DF that I have

- DF1 - clean_dif - [Province, City, District, Sub_District, Cases, Death, Month, ID]
- DF2 - indo_filter_3 - [Object_ID, Village_Code, Village, ID, Province, City, District, Sub_District, Total_Populatiom, Gemoetry]

Here's what I have tried so far and I guess the reason why it doesn't work is cause `Total_Population` is not inside `clean_df` but inside indo_filter_3. How do I create a new calculation field from two different DF (`Indo_filter_3` & `clean_df`) and then create a chloropleth map?

```r
new_df <- clean_df %>%
  group_by(Sub_District, Month) %>%
  summarise(`Cases` = sum(as.numeric(Cases))/Total_Population)


tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(new_df)+
  tm_fill("Cases_Pop",minimize = TRUE) +
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.5)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please include exact error. Which of the two code blocks is the issue you are facing? BTW - you may need to reconcile `Cases_Pop` vs `Cases`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [joining](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) the two data frames before aggregating:

```r
new_df <- clean_df %>%
  inner_join(indo_filter_3, by=c("Province", "City", "District", "Sub_District")) %>%
  group_by(Sub_District, Month) %>%
  summarise(`Cases` = sum(as.numeric(Cases))/Total_Population)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering!  I still get this error message 'Error: Object new_df is neither from class sf, stars, Spatial, Raster, nor SpatRaster.' I do have a geometry column in my indo_filter_3

Comment: But that error does not involve this answer. Correct? I thought your issue involves the `new_df` assignment in calculating `Cases` that require `Total_Population`. Per the comment above, what exactly *doesn't work*? If issue is now mapping that is a different question, not *Aggregating Values From 2 DF in R*.

Comment: Hello that error is pertaining to the code block provided by u which is the part on  summarise(`Cases` = sum(as.numeric(Cases))/Total_Population).  I've tried a lot of methods but I still can't seem to be able to create a chloropleth map for cases for population. Can u help me out

Comment: Very odd, that error should be your attempted graph not the `group_by` calculation unless `clean_df` or `indo_filter_3` is not a `data.frame` but some other class object. Please post a sample like `head` of both data frames with `dput` for [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451).

Comment: Please delete these comments and post the `dput` in your original question. See edit link below post.